# How to parse query string in react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In react-router v3 I could access it with `props.location.query.foo` (if the current location was `?foo=bar`)

In `react-router-dom@4.0.0` `props.location` only has `props.location.search` with is a string like `?foo=bar&other=thing`.

Perhaps I need to manually parse and deconstruct that string to find the value for `foo` or `other`.

Screenshot of `console.log(this.props)`:
[image]
(Note how from `?artist=band` here I'd like to get the value from `artist` which is the value `band`)

Comment: To tie me over I'll import https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string and do it manually.

Comment: you got already the query string here ! nothing with React. It's more about pure Javascript.

Comment: `Easy destructuring assignment of URLSearchParams` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73834476/984471

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Looks like you already assumed correct. The ability to parse query strings was taken out of V4 because there have been requests over the years to support different implementation. With that, the team decided it would be best for users to decide what that implementation looks like. We recommend importing a query string lib. The [one you mentioned](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) has worked great for me so far.

```
const queryString = require('query-string');

const parsed = queryString.parse(props.location.search);
```

You can also use `new URLSearchParams` if you want something native and it works for your needs

```
const search = props.location.search; // could be '?foo=bar'
const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
const foo = params.get('foo'); // bar
```

You can read more about the decision [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410)

Comment: where did you add this so it's available on every route's render?

Comment: URLSearchParams is not available on iOS and SSR. query-string is more stable solution.

Comment: If you need to support IE11, this package currently have issues with it.

Answer (score 24):

I proffer my little `ES6` shape function, awesome, light weight and useful:

```
getQueryStringParams = query => {
    return query
        ? (/^[?#]/.test(query) ? query.slice(1) : query)
            .split('&')
            .reduce((params, param) => {
                    let [key, value] = param.split('=');
                    params[key] = value ? decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : '';
                    return params;
                }, {}
            )
        : {}
};
```

Every thing is here, hope to help you.

Comment: Thumbs up because Internet Explorer STILL doesn't support [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams). WTF Bill Gates.

Comment: @BigRon, Thanks for your upvote, I know, we should use something like this because of backward compatibility and support legacy browsers but sometimes we should have a covenant or contract to Boycott this shitty annoying thing.

In my current project I never check IE even Edge. this is a world project a new Social Network

Answer (score 20):

You may get the following error while creating an optimized production build when using [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) module.

> Failed to minify the code from this file:
>   ./node_modules/query-string/index.js:8

To overcome this, kindly use the alternative module called [stringquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringquery) which does the same process well without any issues while running the build.

```
import querySearch from "stringquery";

var query = querySearch(this.props.location.search);
```

Thank you.

Comment: To get around this, you can also use an older version of `query-string`. You can install it by either doing `yarn add query-string@5` or `npm install query-string@5`

Answer (score 7):

Using third party package is overkill for a simple problem:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const query = new URLSearchParams(
            this.props.location.search
        );

        let data = {};

        for (let params of query.entries()) {
            data[params[0]] = +params[1];
        }

        this.setState({ urldata: data});
}
```

This will simply convert the URL query parameters into an object.

Answer (score 6):

Glad I found this post.  Thanks for the links, after a couple of hours I finally got my code upgraded.

For those of you using query-string, you might have to do something like

```
var nameYouWant = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).nameYouWant;
```

This happened in my case, and `this.props.location.search.theUrlYouWant` would refuse to work.  The second option Tyler mentioned also worked for me with some similar tweaking.

Answer (score 4):

instead of installing a package you can use a simple function for extracting your query params.

```js
//Param Extractor
const parseParams = (params = "") => {
  const rawParams = params.replace("?", "").split("&");
  const extractedParams = {};
  rawParams.forEach((item) => {
    item = item.split("=");
    extractedParams[item[0]] = item[1];
  });
  return extractedParams;
};

//Usage
const params = parseParams(this.props?.location?.search); // returns an object like:
// {id:1,name:john...}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned [UrlSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) and the `.get` method.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer for case of getting query string with react routers `useLocation`:

```
 import useLocation from 'react-router';
 import queryString from 'query-string';

 const handleQueryString = useLocation().search;
 // nice=day&very=sunny
 
 // Get a param
 const { nice } = queryString.parse(useLocation().search)
```

Comment: With `"query-string": "^8.1.0"` this doesn't work: `Attempted import error: 'queryString' is not exported from 'query-string'.`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72174915/2891356), you can make it into a hook:

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const useParsedSearchParams = () => {
    const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

    return Object.fromEntries([...searchParams]);
};

export default useParsedSearchParams;
```

Answer (score -1):

> **use useSearchParams instead of location.search in react-router-v6**

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Chat = ({location}) => {

  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  // pass searchParams as a dependency into the useEffect
  useEffect(()=>{
    const currentParams = Object.fromEntries([...searchParams])

    console.log(currentParams);
  },[searchParams])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).