# Convert search string to query object (after switching to react-router v4)

Tags: url-parameters, window.location, react-router-v4

After switching to react-router 4.0 I dumbly wasted way too much time trying to figure out how to get and set the location.search string to a regular query object.

Even after finally realizing they're not handling query params anymore ([Parse Query Parameters in React Router v4](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-parse-query-parameters-in-react-router-v4)) and turning to [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) I then couldn't remember how to easily extract an object from an iterator. Answer below. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

At least here's a pretty short way to do it with lodash:

```
const getQuery = () => {
  let qp = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
  _.fromPairs([...qp.entries()])
}
```

Oh, and now, on submitting I see: [How to parse query string in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862253/how-to-parse-query-string-in-react-router-v4), but my answer gets the whole object.

Comment: Note URLSearchParams isn't widely supported yet, e.g. in Edge. Please see http://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams