# react-router cannot read location of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass some values from one component to another using query strings.

This is the component I'm passing values from (shortened):

```
export class Button extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {title : "some title"};
}
render() {
    return(
        <Button type="submit" color="primary">
             <Link to="/Template_Main" query={{title: this.state.title}}>Save</Link>
        </Button>
    );
}
}
```

This is how I'm trying to get the value in my other component:

```
const title = this.props.location.query;
```

This is my router:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    browserHistory
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Main';
import TimelineTemplate from './Template_Main';


const App = () => 
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/Template_Main/:title" component={TimelineTemplate} />
        </Route>
       </div>
    </Router>

export default App
```

So, for clarification: I shortened my code to show only what's important. In my Button-component (I chose the name for this post, it has a different name in my actual code), there is also a form in which you can enter a title. When clicking on the button, you are redirected to Template_Main. I want to display the value of title in Template_Main and wanted to pass the value using a query string.
However, I'm making a few mistakes somewhere.
For one, Template_Main is displayed as blank, when I add `:title` to `path="/Template_Main/:title` in the Router. 
When entering a sub-route, like so:

```
<Route path="/Template_Main" component={TimelineTemplate}>
    <Route path="/Template_Main/:title"/>
</ Route>
```

I am redirected, however, then I receive the error message that "location" of undefined cannot be read. I read that I need to pass history to `<Router>`, which I tried and which also failed since I received the error message that there was no property `browserHistory` in `react-router-dom`. Apparently there is no such thing in v4.0.0, so I tried to downgrade to 3.0.0 and then to 2.0.0 using `npm install react-router@x.x.x`, however, I still received the same error message.

I have been researching this for a few hours now and at this point I'm not really sure about what to do.

Did I make any mistakes, either in my code or in how I tried to solve the issue (I tried to describe my course of action as clearly as possible) and do you guy have any ideas about how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

location.query seems to have been discontinued in React router v4. You can try a location.search, props.location.pathname or props.match.params instead.

Here is a [github issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410) for the same problem.

Here is a code example:

```
export class Button extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {title : "some title"};
}
render() {
    return(
        <Button type="submit" color="primary">
             <Link to={"/Template_Main/"+this.state.title}>Save</Link>
        </Button>
    );
}
}
```

and the child component:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Child extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return <div>{this.props.match.params.title}</div>
   }
}

export default withRouter(Child);
```

Router definition should be as follows:

```
<Route path="/Template_Main/:title" component={TimelineTemplate} />
```

Hope it helps.

PS: I am yet to figure out how to pass multiple parameters using this method. If I figure it out, I'll update this answer in the future.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! I adapted my own code and changed it the way you suggested, however, I'm still not sure about how to reference title in my child component, where I want to display it. I used {this.props.match.params.title} but it didn't work and did not return anything. Do you have any suggestion regarding how to do that?

Comment: Okay. Just noticed your Route definition. There seems to be a small syntax error. I'll update my answer with the correct syntax.

Comment: oh also, I passed multiple parameters doing this: `<Link to={"/Template_Main?title="+this.state.title+"&subtitle="+this.state.subtitle}>Save</Link>` don't know if it's the right way but it works for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862253/how-to-parse-query-string-in-react-router-v4 okay I figured it out using this answer (if anyone else, who stumbles across this question, struggles with this.) 
@Raksheet Bhat thank you very much for your help!