# read current URL's query parameter

Tags: reactjs

I have url like this http://localhost/validateemail?email=abc@yahoo.com&token=12345

How can I read the query parameters email and token inside componentWillMount() function?

import React,{Component} from 'react';

```
export default class ValidateEmail extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
  //  alert(this.props.match.params.token);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>Validate email</div>
    );
  }
}
```

can someone please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862253/how-to-parse-query-string-in-react-router-v4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search)`.

This will give you an object of your query parameters.

To get a single entry out of this you can `const foo = query.get(foo)`