# How to Route components in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I need to route to a page when a button is clicked. And I need to pass a `prop` value to that rendering component as well.

Component I need to route to when I click the button = `ProcessData`

my current directories look like this:

```
Route.js
src/
   Main.jsx
   ProcessData.jsx
```

I have a `Route.js` in the root directory and it has like below.

```
<Route path='/banuka/process' component={ProcessData} />
```

But My button (which I use to click to route to this `ProcessData` component is inside `Main.jsx` inside the `src` directory as below:

But now how can I pass the prop `employeeID` to the `ProcessData` component because that it is being called in the `Route.js` file already?

```
const [employeeID, setEmployeeID] = useState("");

return(
<Link to="/banuka/process">
<Button variant="success">
    Process Data
</Button>
</Link>
);
```

I have to render the `ProcessData` component inside this `Link` or any other workaround in `react-router-dom` when this button is clicked and pass the `props` as well?

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use react route params for that or query strings.

If you want to use route param. follow this [instruction](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params):

or for query string: use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string and this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42864252/8389449)

example with params (easy):

```
 <Route path="process/:something" children={<Process />} />
```

in the link component

```
  <Link to="process/some_information_i_need_to_pass">Click me</Link>
```

in Process component:

```
  let { something } = React.useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Params:: {something}</h3>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful :)