# Multiple parameters without / in react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Is it possible to send multiple parameters in a single line **(without separating them with / )**

The params should be like `myawesomeurl.com/?start=true&year=2000`

My router code is:

```
 <Router>
    <Route  path="/:pause?&:year?" component={Main} />
  </Router>
```

The problem I'm having is that the `Main` component is only rendered if I access `http://myawesomeurl.com/&` with the & at the end or send parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to send it as one parameter and parse it in the other component

Comment: Thanks for responding! Could you show me how the Route path should be?

Comment: all search parameters will be available in `this.props.location.search` I guess. See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47100731/4374566

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings Thank you so much!!! Worked!!