# React JS - How to render same component with different ids without page refreshing?

Tags: reactjs

I have a navbar with links

```
render() {
    return (
      <Link to={"/test/1"} >Task 1 </Link>
      <Link to={"/test/2"} >Task 2 </Link>
      <Link to={"/test/3"} >Task 3 </Link>
      <Link to={"/test/4"} >Task 4 </Link>
    )
}
```

And i set the route to call the corresponding component with dynamic `id` to display the contents based on the `id`

And my called **Test** component has the following code

```
render() {
    return (            
        <div>
            <div>
                {this.props.id}
            </div>
        </div> 
    );
}
```

And i need to change the contents in my component based on the `id` passed in the route **without refreshing**. But `{this.props.id}` does not populates the value there. How can i solve this?

Comment: because that value will not get passed as `this.props.id`, it will be inside `params`, access that by using `this.props.match.params.id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-router: How to get parameter value from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-router-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using React router, you will have an object called match which contains various other properties. Among them one is params which contains all the parameters you pass through a route.

Accessing routes and its params should be done using `props.match.params.id` (Assuming you have configured your route as  `<Route path="/test/:id" component={YourComponent} />`

Comment: My route is `<Route path={"test/:id"} component={Test} />`  and i'm getting the error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined"

Comment: Can you post your Test component aswell?

Comment: Test component is which tries to display the `id` mentioned in my question. Please refer.

Comment: When i avoid `match` and tried as `this.props.params.id` i'm getting the result. But now the issue facing is `componentDidMount()` given in the **Test** component is not working.

Comment: Whats happening in componentDidMount?

Comment: Just given `componentDidMount(){ console.log(this.props.params.id) }` but nothing happens in my console

Comment: componentdidmount will be only invoked once.

Check your componentdidupdate method

Comment: This works but when i added an API call inside this componentDidUpdate, it gets looping the API call as the result makes an update and this update function invokes

Comment: Well.. What are you doing in componentdidupdate after API call?

Comment: I was just setting the values received from the api to state variables.

Comment: Setting state in componentdidupdate will make component to re-render again and again making it to go to an infinite loop. (do you have a condition where it stops doing setState in componentdidudpate??

Comment: I just used `componentWillReceiveProps`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
const Parent = () => (
    <div>
        <Link to="/test/1">Task 1</Link>
        <Link to="/test/2">Task 2</Link>
        <Link to="/test/3">Task 3</Link>
        <Link to="/test/4">Task 4</Link>

        <Route path="/test/:id" component={Child} />
    </div>
)

const Child = (props) => (
    <div>
        <h3>ID: {props.match.params.id}</h3>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query string to pass the ID to the component,

```
render() {
    return (
      <Link to={`/test/1?id=${id1}`} >Task 1 </Link>
      <Link to={`/test/2?id=${id2}`} >Task 2 </Link>
      <Link to={`/test/3?id=${id3}`} >Task 3 </Link>
      <Link to={`/test/4?id=${id4}`} >Task 4 </Link>
    )
}
```

You can then get the query param from props if you are using react router which I suspect you are.

```
render() {
    return (            
        <div>
            <div>
                {this.props.location.query.id}
            </div>
        </div> 
    );
}
```

As G_S also mentioned, you can access the path param like so:

```
<div>{props.match.params.id}</div>
```