# props is not defined when using MapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I get to my homepage, I have a current state that is an object made of objects that are my articles.

```
articles:
0: {id:'3',body:'ballon pied ball…football'}
1: {id:'2',body:'Encore du Lorem … article'}
2: {id:'1',body:'Lorem Ipsum Dolo… article'}
```

It corresponds to the list of article on the homepage; when I click on one of them, it should redirect me to the specific page of the article where I can read it. (/article/:id)

So I try to create an Article component that would render the title, subtitle and body of it. But I get 'props is undefined' as an error:

`Article.js` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const Article = ({match}) => (
<div className="aboutpage-wrapper">
  <div className="container">
    <h1>{match.params.id}</h1>
    {console.log(props)}
{/*    <h2>{props.article.title}</h2>
    <h3>{props.article.subtitle}</h3>
    <p>{props.article.body}</p>*/}
  </div>
</div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ article: state.articles[1] });
// I try to access articles[1] just to see if it works.

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Article);
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in your Article component you destructure the props: `({ match })`, therefore you won't have access to the `props`.

If you want to access the `props` directly in your Article component, then you should do this:

```
const Article = props => (...);
```

If you want continuing  destructuring the props, then list all the needed props fields, as follows:

```
const Article = ({ match, article, ...rest }) => (...);
```

Comment: thank you @Jordan Enev! then how can I get the right article with the specific id ?

Comment: At `mapStateToProps` as a second argument, you have to have `props`.  Depending on what library you're using (I guess react-router), in the `props` there will be the `id` of the current article.

Something like that:
```const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({ article: state.articles[props.params.id] });```

Comment: I almost get it; however  I got 'cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Do you use `react-router`  package?

Comment: I exactly use: `react-router-dom`

Comment: Actually, I just realised my state is an Array of Object, not an object of objects: `[{id:1, title: 'title1'}, {id:2, title: 'title2'}, {id:3, title: 'title3'}]`

Comment: Please checkout this [question / answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35352638/4312466), in order to understand how to get the URL params, using react-router. Once you get the article id, you just have to find the article by this id. You can use `.find` method.

Comment: OK I managed to get the right article using this: `const mapStateToProps = (state,props) => ({ article: state.articles.find(function (obj) { return obj.id === props.match.params.id; })});
`

however, `console.log(props.article) returns an object`but `props.article.title` is not defined, why ?