# Accessing URL param in react-router render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

this is a quick question but I haven't found a solution so far:

I want to access the URL parameter with react-router v4 using the render method. Everything I found so far was only passing the component like this:

`<Route path="/:id" component={Child} />`

But I want to use the render method like this:

`<Route path="/:id" render={() => (<Wrapper> <Child /> </Wrapper>)} />`

However, the `match` prop is undefined when I try to access the `id` parameter with `props.match.params.id` in my `Child` component.

Any idea how I could use a render function and still access the url parameter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - How to get parameter value from query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass down props from `Route` to `Child`:

```
<Route path="/:id" render={(props) => (<Wrapper> <Child {...props} /> </Wrapper>)} />
```

or :

```
<Route path="/:id" render={(props) => (<Wrapper> <Child id={props.match.params.id} /> </Wrapper>)} />
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I actually tried that before but it didn't work because of a custom `PrivateRoute` component that I built myself and where I didn't pass the props to the render function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `location.search` to get that query string in the URL, and get the path from `location.pathname`

```
<Route
      path="/about"
      render={({ location, history }) => (
           <div>
                 <p>We are at: {location.pathname}</p>
                 <p>Query string is: {location.search}</p>
           </div>
      )}
/>
```