# How to get authentication to the api

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, oauth-2.0, create-react-app

I want to make a image search web app with unsplash api, but I can't seem to get it to work, I am following instructions on here https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-js#dependencies also there is additional information in here https://unsplash.com/documentation#authorization-workflow. I am new to authorization.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Unsplash, { toJson } from 'unsplash-js';
import './App.css';

const unsplash = new Unsplash({
  applicationId: '1424074b20f17701ec8c0601fd15ca686c70e2cb0e645f8137533d8063e664bc',
  secret: 'd47bcd8287983e24da69c37348b21bee55b4c808390413f52fa6aa545b11debc',
  callbackUrl: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
  headers: {
    "Accept-Version": "v1"
  }
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const authenticationUrl = unsplash.auth.getAuthenticationUrl([
      "public",
      "read_user",
      "write_user",
      "read_photos",
      "write_photos"
    ]);
    location.assign(authenticationUrl);
    unsplash.auth.userAuthentication(query.code)
      .then(toJson)
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json.access_token)
        unsplash.auth.setBearerToken(json.access_token);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Auth err', err));

  }

  handleClick() {
    let query = document.getElementById('input').value;
    unsplash.search.photos(query, 1) //function provided by api
      .then(toJson)
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form id='form'>
          <input type='text' id='input' ></input>
          <input type='submit' id='submit' onClick={this.handleClick} ></input>
        </form>
        <div id='field' >
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The error:

```
https://unsplash.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=1424074b20f17701ec8c0601fd15ca686c70e2cb0e645f8137533d8063e664bc&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=public+read_user+write_user+read_photos+write_photos App.js:29
 ReferenceError: query is not defined App.js:31
The above error occurred in the <App> component:
    in App (at index.js:7)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
 index.js:2178
 ReferenceError: query is not defined App.js:31
./src/App.js
  Line 31:  'query' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: Could you at least paste the error message you are getting from catch() ? In what way it doesn't work?

Comment: yeah, sorry. Updated the question

Comment: well the error shows, query is not defined. Look at `query.code` in `componentDidMount`

Comment: Yeah, I think I need to get the authentication code from the url when I get redirected to the `authenticationUrl` and pass that code as `query`. But I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that:

`// The OAuth code will be passed to your callback URL as a query string`

Before that:
*Now that you have an authentication URL, you'll want to redirect the user to it.* `location.assign(authenticationUrl);`

So:

1. You will probably need some routing solution like React Router or similar.
2. On click, redirect a user to the URL (authenticationURL) using your router (React Router example: `import { Redirect } from react-router-dom` then `<Redirect to={url} />` in the code.
3. Once user is authorised, Unsplash will drive him back to your app with `code` in the URL query string. The presence of the `code` you may want to capture in `componentDidMount()` or `componentDidUpdate()` (depending on your app/solution). The query string you should be able to capture from the Router. If you are using React Router you can follow the post: [How to get parameter value from query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)
4. Pass the code as a parameter. The rest looks ok.