# Trouble getting variables out of the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to react/redux and I was wondering if there is a method to pull variables out of an url example  www.url.com/(123)
I wish to take the 123 outta it and pass it through other functions but am at lost at this point.

Comment: Take a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a React question, just a general JavaScript one.

One way to do it is:

```
const url = 'http://www.url.com/123';
const path = new URL(url).pathname;
console.log(path);
```

Another way is to split the URL into an array of segments.

```
let path = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
```

Comment: what about 2 different components, the first is to link to the next page and the second component is to catch the variable at the end of the link will this work too? cause i cant figure out how to put this into my code.

Comment: You can use `split` to grab the different URL segments. Updated above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you should be using `location.pathname` to get that ;)