# How to send data via LINK in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink

I'm working with react js and I'm looking for a solution to send data via Link. When I click on a menu it redirect me to another page and I want to get a data from previous page so this is what I did:

```
 <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>

      <Link to="/servicecontreservice" params={{ dataToSend: '55' }} >Proposer un service</Link>
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>
      <Link to="/prix">Proposer un montant</Link>
    </Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
```

and in the an anther file there is this code to get data from Link:

```
class myClass extends React.Component {



  state = {
    value:`${this.props.dataToSend}`}



  render() {
    return(
<p> {this.state.value}</p>
     );
  }
}

myClass.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles()(myClass);
```

...but I get no data, when I use console.log(`${this.props.eventName}`) I got "undifined".

Comment: What lib are you using?

Comment: i'm using react-router-dom   for Link and antd for the Menu.item

Comment: I think you want `this.props.params.dataToSend`

Comment: to get your params you should use this: this.props.route.params.dataToSend

Comment: @AtlanteAvila now i get this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Comment: @MarouenMhiri  i got this now ; TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md#to-object

Comment: `<Link to={{
  pathname: '/courses',
  search: '?sort=name',
  hash: '#the-hash',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
}}/>`

Comment: You should send your 'params' in the as the value to the search key in the object.  Also, you need to note that the React component looks really wonky to me. I haven't been able to test it, but you're setting state in the wrong way, you should use the constructor and super methods.

Comment: @AtlanteAvila when i write Link this way how can i get the params ?

Comment: @MaryemSamet: which version of 'react-router-dom' do u use?

Comment: Try to `console.log(location.search);` you will need to parse this with a library called query-string. `import qs from 'query-string';`. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string

Comment: thank u that helped , the problem i had is i didn't write the contructor and super  , thank you very much for your help