# React: How can i read a Code from the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, url

I use the Firebase SDK in my React-App. If a user wants to reset his password, he will be redirected to a page within my app. Firebase requires the code to be inserted in the URL for password reset.

The Code will be saved in `this.props.location.search` When i log this prop, i get his:

```
?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=3ckTC8-xBAzTUCbrWQCrg4i0kD6F2_wOmuaeiHLsQH8AAAFmERVurw&apiKey=AIzaSyDC3GXJ2rcONeBYTu9FBjZEfJbEsaJMWNo&lang=en
```

How can i get only the Code from this URL Parameters?

Thanks for your answer and for your help

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with firebase or ReactJS, you will find answers in the linked duplicate ^

Comment: I think OP is looking for [_this_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use any dummy site name to construct URL and do this,

```
let params = (new URL(`http://dummy.com${this.props.location.search}`)).searchParams;
let code = params.get("oobCode")
```

more info, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

Comment: please upvote my answer if it helped :)