# How to access URL parameter inside the ComponentDidMount method in react correctly

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem like this. I am developing a React application. There is an Url like this

http://localhost:3000/drivershow/0x6E2C0A2f1a7e8fb7C33b3826FF14F95C90535557

I want to access the 0x6E2C0A2f1a7e8fb7C33b3826FF14F95C90535557 part from the URL. To do that I have tried something like this by following some question in the StackOverflow.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string'

class DriversShow extends Component{
    async componentDidMount(props){
        const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
        console.log(values);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>Haiiiiiiiiii</div>
        );
    }
}

export default DriversShow;
```

But it consoles log undefined. Can someone help me to solve this problem? I tried some other examples by searching in the Google but those were unable to make a sense. Thank You!!

Comment: I think this would help you [How to get parameter value from query string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37568368/3759156)

Comment: Can you add your route definition here? Is it something like /driveshow/:id ?

Comment: How does this url happen? Is it appended ? Is it a route ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is the `useParams()`. React-Router introduce this since version 5.1 to easily get the url params, you can check the [official example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams).

```js
<Route path="/drivershow/:showid" component={DriversShow} />
```

Be careful that `useParams()` must be inside functional component.

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"

function DriversShow(){
    const { showid } = useParams()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there was some misunderstanding about `location.search` vs `location.params`. The `0x6E2C0A2f1a7e8fb7C33b3826FF14F95C90535557` should be `location.params`. Could you provide us with your react-router's version?

If you are using V4, you should follow this [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) to get location params.

If you are using the older version, you can get request params inside the `componentDidmount` lifecycle like this:

```
componentDidMount () {
    const { handle } = this.props.match.params

    fetch(`https://api.twitter.com/user/${handle}`)
      .then((user) => {
        this.setState(() => ({ user }))
      })
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Route path="/users/:id" component={Hello} />
```

on componentDidMount used

```
this.props.match.params.id
```