# Active state will not stay after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add active class to the links and change active state while navigating page. I have tried with this but changes not applying after switching between links. (not working after page reload)

**Here is my code**

```js
$('#shortcuts-main > li').click(function (e) {
    $(".shortcut-link-active").removeClass("shortcut-link-active");
    $(this).addClass("shortcut-link-active");
});
```

```css
a{
  color:black;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  display:block;
}

.shortcut-link-active a{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="shortcuts-main">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No ajax using..

Comment: You can keep active links as part of url query and can use that after page refresh to select back the active links.

Comment: Example of getting query params from url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modification done to the DOM will not persist after the page is refreshed. A solution for this is to save the data on the client and then read after reloading.

Unfortunately `localstorage` won't work on Stackoverflow, but at least you can see some code:

```js
$('#shortcuts-main > li').click(function(e) {
  $(".shortcut-link-active").removeClass("shortcut-link-active");
  $(this).addClass("shortcut-link-active");
  console.log('id:', $(e.target).data('id'))
  localStorage.setItem('shortcut-link-active', $(e.target).data('id'));
});

const lastActiveLink = localStorage.getItem('shortcut-link-active');
if (lastActiveLink) {
  $('#shortcuts-main')
    .find(`[data-id='${lastActiveLink}']`)
    .parent()
    .addClass('shortcut-link-active')
}
```

```css
a {
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.shortcut-link-active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="shortcuts-main">
  <li>
    <a data-id="link-id-1" href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-id="link-id-2" href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-id="link-id-3" href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-id="link-id-4" href="#">Link 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```