# How to pass props with react-router using onClick methods

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im new to react and even newer to react-router and i create a react app which contains a few routes but some routes need the same data (props). I want to transfer those props through a onClickEvent when pressing a button on a present page. I read about some attempts like binding the onClick listener on a button to a method like

```
handleOnClick(){    
  this.props.history.push('/booking')
 ))
```

to redirect to a route called "booking". But how can i pass a single prop of my present page or the whole set of props to this new page? Is there any solution for this and how can i access the props on the redirected route?

Here is my Index.js, more routes will be added soon:

```
const routing = (
 <Router>
   <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
     <Route path="/booked" component={Booked} />
   </div>
 </Router>
 );

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The routingtree should be the following: I have one mainview in my App.js which renders components of BookingItems. Within a Bookingitem i have multiple props. When i book some of the items, i should be redirected to my Booked.js component.

Within any BookingItems i have a button which should do the redirecting to the Booked.js.

BookingItems:

```
onButtonClick() {
  this.props.history.push("/booked");
 }

render(){
 return(
          <div className="alignCenterDiv">
            <button
              onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)}
              align="center"
              className="buttonBooking"
            >
              Buchen
            </button>
          </div>
)}
```

Booked:
Here i want to access any of the props i had in BookingItems or i created in booking item to pass it to Booked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you redirect using:

```
this.props.history.push('/booking', {
  myProp: this.props.myProp,
  foo: 'bar'
})
```

Then, in `/booking` page, you can access the variables like so:

```
console.log(this.props.location.state)
/*
  {
    myProp: '...',
    foo: 'bar'
  }
*/
```

Comment: thats what i wanted to do! Thank you so much sir! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

You route

```
<Route path="/booking/:id" .../>
```

On Click

```
handleOnClick(){    
  this.props.history.push('/booking/12345')
 ))
```

Booking component

```
componentDidMount(){
  console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
}
```

For alternative options you can read this: [How to get parameter value from query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Another option (after question update it sounds like a better option) is to use **redux** (or something similar). When you click on the button you dispatch an action to set *selectedBookingItem* in global state to the clicked item. Then navigation (look at the **react-router-redux**). Booking component is connected to the **redux** and selectedBookingItem is mapped to the prop (*mapStateToProps*).

Comment: thanks for this attempt. It works but it doesnt satisfy what i want to do, cause this way i can only pass one prop (in this case: id) and i also dont want to see that prop in my link (..:/booking/12345). Any other solutions to pass more than one prop?

Comment: @Alex, how about path "/booking/:id/:name/:someOtherProp" ?

Comment: @Alex, if you don't want to see this data in the path then probably you need some state management like redux. What properties do you need to path to the component?

Comment: I edited my main post for hopefully better understanding. I need to pass props like name, destination, price, and much more.

Comment: thanks for updating, i will try it tomorrow with redux, but im basicaly competly new to this too :)

Comment: @Alex, Good luck. I hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your BookingItems file, you can use `Link` component from `react-router-dom` to redirect to the `/booked` route as well as send data (any state, prop, data) to the route(when the button is clicked).

```
render(){
 return(
       <div className="alignCenterDiv">
          <Link to="/booked" state={yourDesiredPropsOrStates}>
            <button
              onClick={this.onButtonClick.bind(this)}
              align="center"
              className="buttonBooking"
            >
              Buchen
            </button>
          <Link>
       </div>
)}
```

Now, you can use the `useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom` to receive the the data that you sent from `BookingItem` file.

In `Booked.js` :-

```js
const location = useLocation();
console.log("data coming from BookingItems", location.state);
```