# React render component with prop on click of a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-component

I want users to be able to click Buy button and that will redirect to a checkout component (go to a new page and show the checkout component). How do I show the Checkout component when users click Buy button ?

Checkout Component also requires a prop (price of item). How do I do this:  after clicking the button?

Button code:

```
                       <Button
                        className={classes.root} 
                        variant="contained"  
                        color="primary"
                        disabled={loading}
                        >
                          Buy Coupon
                        </Button>
```

My Checkout Component takes in Price/Amount:

```
const CheckoutForm = ({ price }) ....
```

Is this on the right track? :

```
<Route exact path="/checkout" render={(props) => <Checkout {...props}/>}/>
```

Comment: Does it redirect to a new page? are you using a router? or just plain showing another component based on the click?

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect to a checkout component"?

Comment: I want it to go to a new page

Comment: To navigate onClick there is an example here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244731/react-router-how-to-manually-invoke-link On how to pass props, there is an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083066/how-to-pass-props-with-react-router-using-onclick-methods

Comment: The first link It uses "this.props", I am using react hooks and not sure how to use that