# How to read URL Parameters within Component in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

This may sound dump, but how I am supposed to read the URL and get its values from an URL in React JS. 
I have been told to use the QueryString in order to handle the GET parameters.

The Url looks has following structure:

```
localhost/test?id=xxx&value=yyyy
```

in the component class I'm using following code:

```
class test extends Component {

  func() {
    const params = queryString.parse(location.search);

     //here I get: {?id=xxx&value=yyyy}
  }
}
```

How does it come that the Questionmark Sign has been retrived also?
And how to fix it, so that I am able to get those values without crafting too much?

Comment: @Ashish, the question is the same, but the answer does not fit fully my requirements. I do not want to use window.location.search when there is some npm libraries which may handle it in much better way-

Comment: Just for the sake of getting parameters, i dont think using any library is good idea. When you can achieve this with a small util function of your own. I would prefer that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're utilizing `react-router`, it's pretty easy. See this: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-query-strings/

Comment: Do I have to use the react-router, even if I only want to retrive the url without doing anything else? For some reason accessing the params.id results in undefined..

Comment: If you don't want to use `react-router` you could try this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

Comment: I'm using it already.. but the question is: how to get the individual values from it?

Comment: If you use the `query-string` pacakge, it has a `.parse()` function that creates an object from the query string of the URL. So, let's say the url was `?search=something?dog=cat`. After calling the `parse` method, you would have an object like the following `{ search: 'something', dog: 'cat' } ` that you could access the individual properties from where you need them

Comment: for some reason I was using the querystring not the query-string package..Not sure if there are any significant differences. Right now, I will remove the prevous one and install the query-string for that... maybe its the reason why the ignoreQueryPrefix: true  Parameter has worked as expected.

Comment: the problem was obvious the package.. Right now it works and I'm able to read the indvidual values.

Answer (score 15):

#### You can use `URLSearchParams`:

```
const windowUrl = window.location.search;
const params = new URLSearchParams(windowUrl);
// params['id']
```

#### Or, if you desire to use `react-router` solutions, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37568368/695377).

Comment: react-router is my desired approach. For now I just only wanted to read the GET  paramaters.