# How to access get parameters in react route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I try to get parameters in the URL of my react App in a structured way. I have parameters called id1 and id2 and it's possible to see them like this

```
console.log("this.props.location.search", this.props.location.search)
```

The URL with the parameters will be linked like this

```
<a href="compare/?id1=6bf45ef0-962e-11e9-923e-972a9f2b848f&amp;id2=58e82e60-961d-11e9-ae32-47571549c9a2">
    <button class="ui yellow button">
       Comparison
    </button>
</a>
```

I found solutions like

```
this.props.location.query.id1

this.props.match.params
```

but this.props.match.params are empty and this.props.location.query does not exist

In addition I tested to set some things in the route. But the following crashes the whole app just showing an empty screen

```
      <Route exact path="/compare(/:id1)(/:id2)" component={Compare} />
```

If I do

```
      <Route exact path="/compare/:id1?/:id2?" component={Compare} />
```

the App is running again showing the parameters as undefined

```
match:
  isExact: true
  params:
    id1: undefined
    id2: undefined
```

Comment: This may be helpful to you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're mixing your url parameters with your query string.

In your `href` you should have something like this:

```
<a href="compare/6bf45ef0-962e-11e9-923e-972a9f2b848f/58e82e60-961d-11e9-ae32-47571549c9a2">
  <button class="ui yellow button">
      Comparison
  </button>
</a>
```

Your route will look like this:

```
<Route exact path="/compare/:id1/:id2" component={Compare} />
```

In your `Compare` component you will be able to access your parameters with `this.props.match.params.id1` and `this.props.match.params.id2` and make the request to the server that will make the comparison with your query string.

Try it out and let me know if it helps.