# react-router-dom useParams() inside class component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to load a details view based on a react-router-dom route that should grab the URL parameter (id) and use that to further populate the component.

My route looks like `/task/:id` and my component loads fine, until I try to grab the :id from the URL like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

class TaskDetail extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let { id } = useParams();
        this.fetchData(id);
    }

    fetchData = id => {
        // ...
    };

    render() {
        return <div>Yo</div>;
    }
}

export default TaskDetail;
```

This triggers the following error and I'm unsure where to correctly implement useParams().

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

The docs only show examples based on functional components, not class based.

Comment: Hooks don't work in class based components

Comment: @Dupocas ok that makes sense. What would you suggest, rewrite the class to a function or use a class and try to grab the url parameter some other way?

Comment: Both valid alternatives. Can you post the code for `useParams`? Maybe turn it into an `HOC`?

Comment: Can anyone comment on _why_ this is limited to function components? I've been using React for maybe 8 months and things like this are still a regular "gotcha" for me, would love to understand it better.

Comment: For function in React Route v6 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70251443/624533

Answer (score 116):

**Version <= 5:**

You can use `withRouter` to accomplish this.  Simply wrap your exported classed component inside of `withRouter` and then you can use `this.props.match.params.id` to get the parameters instead of using `useParams()`.  You can also get any `location`, `match`, or `history` info by using `withRouter`.  They are all passed in under `this.props`

Using your example it would look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class TaskDetail extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const id = this.props.match.params.id;
        this.fetchData(id);
    }

    fetchData = id => {
        // ...
    };

    render() {
        return <div>Yo</div>;
    }
}

export default withRouter(TaskDetail);
```

Simple as that!

Comment: I got an error when use withRouter in react router dom v6: `Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: Yea it looks like v6 is not using it anymore.  You can still import it from `react-router`.  I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: `react-router` do not contain `withRouter` too. I got a same error result

Comment: here is the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) for using it.  maybe this will help a littl better

Comment: this is no longer a valid solution - withRouter is not available in `react-router` 6.

Comment: updated answer to reflect this

Comment: so sad, from react-router v6 ``Replace all uses of withRouter with hooks``

Answer (score 30):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function withParams(Component) {
  return props => <Component {...props} params={useParams()} />;
}


class TaskDetail extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let { id } = this.props.params;
        this.fetchData(id);
    }

    fetchData = id => {
        // ...
    };

    render() {
        return <div>Yo</div>;
    }
}

export default withParams(TaskDetail);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Really helped me, wrapping the class component in a function to work as a custom HOC is the key

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, literally only one solution I have found that works for me...

Answer (score 19):

Since hooks wont work with class based components you can wrap it in a function and pass the properties along:

```
class TaskDetail extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { id } = this.props.params;
        // ...
    }
}

export default (props) => (
    <TaskDetail
        {...props}
        params={useParams()}
    />
);
```

But, like @michael-mayo said, I expect this is what `withRouter` is already performing.

Comment: thank you for this - `withRouter` is no longer an option since it is removed from react-router ^6. This solution works and gives me more time before I need to deprecate large class based components.

Comment: Oh yeah, they did go full in on hooks recently. I'm glad this will help keep some class based components running

Comment: This should be selected as the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Params get passed down through props on the match object.

```
props.match.params.yourParams
```

source: https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router

Here is an example from the docs destructing the props in the arguments.

```
const App = ({ match: { params } }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AddTodo />
      <VisibleTodoList filter={params.filter || 'SHOW_ALL'} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a very clean solution to avoid hooks but is there a caveat? Why do the react-router docs do not mention this as an alternative and only show the hooks example in the documentation?

Answer (score 6):

[You can not call a hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#but-what-is-a-hook) such as "useParams()" from a React.Component.

Easiest way if you want to use hooks and have an existing react.component is to create a function then call the React.Component from that function and pass the parameter.

```
import React from 'react';
import useParams from "react-router-dom";

import TaskDetail from './TaskDetail';

function GetId() {

    const { id } = useParams();
    console.log(id);

    return (
        <div>
            <TaskDetail taskId={id} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default GetId;
```

Your switch route will still be something like

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/task/:id" component={GetId} />
</Switch>
```

then you will be able to get the id from from the props in your react component

```
this.props.taskId
```

Comment: one liner `Route` with `Component` works,  rather `<Route>code</Route>` not works why so?

Comment: It should be { useParams } instead of useParams in the import statement.

Answer (score 5):

In react-router-dom-v6 you can easily use useParams() in functional components but when it gets to the class component you have to create HOC (higher-order component) because hooks don't support class components:

```
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export const withRouter = (WrappedComponent) => (props) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return <WrappedComponent {...props} params={params} navigate={navigate} />;
};
```

Then export your component from your HOC and give your component as a parameter. like below:

```
export default withRouter(YourComponentName);
```

After that you can easily access the url id with `this.props.params.id` and you can navigate to other components with `this.props.navigate("/YourPath")`

Answer (score 3):

**React Route v5**

Query params can be read and processed as JSON using `withRouter` and `queryString` as follow:

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import queryString from 'query-string';
    
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const params = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
        console.log('Do something with it', params);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Hi!</div>;
    }
}

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

SmujMaiku is rigth!!! His answer works perfectly. This is how work today with react-router v6

```
enter code here
   
   import React ,{Component} from 'react'
   import {  useParams } from "react-router-dom";
  import PokeDescription from '../components/PokeDescription'

 class PokeInfoConteiner extends Component{

 render(){
    
    let urlPokemon= "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/"
    
    
    const {idPokemon} = this.props.params 
    console.log(idPokemon)

    return(
        
        <div>
            <PokeDescription pokeImage={`${urlPokemon}${idPokemon}.png?raw=true`}/>
            <p>{}</p>
            
        </div>

    )

}
```

}

```
   export default (props) => (
        <PokeInfoConteiner
            {...props}
            params={useParams()}
   />)
```

Answer (score 1):

**in React Router V6** :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

/* This is a higher order component that 
*  inject a special prop   to our component.
*/ 
function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouter(props) {
    let params = useParams()
    return <Component {...props} params={params} />
  }
  return ComponentWithRouter
}
class TaskDetail extends React.Component {
    state={
      id : ""
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
        id : this.props.params.id
      })
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
      return {
        id : nextProps.params.id
      }
    }
    fetchData = id => {
        // ...
    };

    render() {
        return <div>Yo</div>;
    }
}


const HOCTaskDetail = withRouter(TaskDetail);

export default HOCTaskDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-router-dom v6, there is no hook such as **withRouter** therefore my advice to you is to convert your class-based component to a functional component to use **useParams** hook in your component otherwise you can create a higher-order component to pass your class-based component.

Comment: ...here's an example of how it can be done:
[Edit react-router-v5-to-v6-compatibility](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v5-to-v6-compatibility-tlhb4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: this is quite painful on large components!

Comment: There we go https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-jennings-l7qq93

Comment: @k90mirzaei Your solution worked nice!

Answer (score 0):

**React Route v6**

My friends, I tried to use in class but I failed to find any doc about it. So after many hours of searching and trying hard this is (in function). Now (i.e when I'm writing this post) there is only limited resource about v6. But there are many for <v6.

Here I'm using **useState**,**useEffect**,**useParams**,**axios**.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Post = () => {
    let { post_id } = useParams();
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState({ post: null, countSecrets: 0, ui: '' });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (posts.countSecrets === 0) {
            const doAxe = (a) => {
                axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + post_id)
                    .then((res) => {
                        setPosts(s => ({ ...s, value: res.data }));
                        doUI(res.data)
                        // console.log(res.data)
                    });
            }
            setPosts(s => ({ ...s, countSecrets: s.countSecrets + 1 }));
            doAxe()
        }
    }, [posts, post_id]);
    let doUI = (x) => {
        // console.log('x' + x.title)
        const finalPost = (x !== null) ? (
            <div className="post">
                <h4 className="center">{x.title}</h4>
                <p>{x.body}</p>
            </div>
        ) : (
            <div className="center">Loading posts...</div>
        );
        setPosts(s => ({ ...s, ui: finalPost }));
    }
    return (
        <div className="container">
            {posts.ui}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Post;
```

**NOTE:**
I faced **useEffect** looping. I prevented it with a key.

**HOPE:** This may help someone!

**Reference:**

- [using useParams](https://karoldabrowski.com/blog/getting-parameters-from-url-in-a-react-application/)
- [state inside function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
- [preventing loop from useEffect](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-infinite-loop/)

Answer (score 0):

as you know the useParams() is a hook for react-router-dom.
you can not use this inside the componentDidMount() or useEffect() because both of them are method that called during the Mounting phase of the React Life-cycle i.e after the component is rendered.
you have a solution:
create or define another function outside the componentDidMount() to define useParams then call it inside the componentDidMount.
know every thing will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working example. :)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function withParams(Component) {
  return (props) => <Component {...props} params={useParams()} />;
}

class ProductDetails extends Component {
  handleSave = () => {
    // Navigate to /products
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Product Details - {this.props.params.id}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleSave}>Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withParams(ProductDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks only work on functional components,
you have to make that ocmponent a functional component

Answer (score 0):

## Fixed by creating a wrapping function

I needed to pass params to my SaxjaxApp.js from index.js using react-router-dom v6.
In v6 `Switch` has been changed to `Routes`

I got the useParams working with a class component by following  Mohamed MAZEK's  idea in post 20 using a wrapping function.

I needed to access the `sessionId` part of the url when it was available.

ie in `localhost:3000/shared/123XYZId`
I needed the `123XYZId` part.

make note of this line : `<Route path="/shared/:sessionId" element={<SaxjaxAppWrapper />} />` in the index.js below.

`:sessionId` denotes that `useParams` has a property called `sessionId`, that can be accessed by:

`const {sessionId} = useParams()` from a functional component.

In my index.js file I did this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles/style.scss";

import SaxjaxAppWrapper from "SaxjaxAppWrapper";
import SaxjaxApp from "./SaxjaxApp";

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
//INFO: to learn about react-roue-dom v6 https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5

root.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/shared/:sessionId" element={<SaxjaxAppWrapper />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<SaxjaxApp />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  // </React.StrictMode>
);
```

This line `<Route path="/shared/:sessionId" element={<SaxjaxAppWrapper />} />` calls my wrapping function, whereas the default path `/` just calls the class component.

I had to create a separate file to hold the wrapping function I don't know why:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import SaxjaxApp from "SaxjaxApp";
    
 function SaxjaxAppWrapper() {

//I use the params here and store them to pass as props 
  let { sessionId } = useParams();

  return (
//I pass the sessionId from the url params as a prop to my SaxjaxApp class component here
      <SaxjaxApp sessionId={sessionId} />
  );
}
    
export default SaxjaxAppWrapper;
```

My class component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles/style.scss";

class SaxjaxApp extends Component {
 state = {
   octave: 4,
 };

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   //... initialise stuff
 }

//... a lot of methods

render() {
//Access the param here
   const { sessionId } = this.props;
     <>
         <div>
           keybordId={sessionId ? sessionId : "no id was passed"}
         </div>
     </>

   );
 }
}

export default SaxjaxApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Errors because :**

- Hooks Used Only In Functional Component
- In deceleration of the id value use const alternate of use let because you don't need to change the id value

**Corrected code:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
function TaskDetail() {
    const { id } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(id);
    }, [id]);

    const fetchData = (id) => {
        // ... Implement data fetching logic here
    };

    return <div>Yo</div>;
}

export default TaskDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ssssh, hack ahead

If you feel rebellious to React's whole "you have to use hooks because we decided it is a better way for you to maintain your code", here is a solution:

```
import {UNSAFE_RouteContext} from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react'

class FreedomToClassComponents extends React.Component {
    // seems like it is marked unsafe because it is internal: 
    //    https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/13ac1b6c5cc2c3f99629bed6ed0ccc8542de0d94/packages/react-router/index.ts#L328
    static contextType = UNSAFE_RouteContext


    render() {
        // if this breaks, just check what they are doing at: 
        //    https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/13ac1b6c5cc2c3f99629bed6ed0ccc8542de0d94/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L293C17-L293C26
        let {matches} = this.context
        let routeMatch = matches[matches.length - 1];
        const params = routeMatch ? routeMatch.params : {};

        // say route is "/task/:id" and url is mywebsite.com/task/12, 
        // this will print '{id: 12}'
        console.log(params)

        return React.createElement("div", {}, "bonus: if you define elements like this you don't need jsx")
    }
}
export default FreedomToClassComponents;
```

bit more organized version:

```
// ComponentWithRouteParams.js
import {UNSAFE_RouteContext} from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react'
class ComponentWithRouteParams extends React.Component {
    static contextType = UNSAFE_RouteContext
    get route_params() {
        let {matches} = this.context
        let routeMatch = matches[matches.length - 1];
        const params = routeMatch ? routeMatch.params : {};
    }
}
export default ComponentWithRouteParams


// FreedomToClassComponents.js
import ComponentWithRouteParams from "./ComponentWithRouteParams"
import React from 'react'

class FreedomToClassComponents extends ComponentWithRouteParams {
    render() {
        console.log(this.route_params)
        return React.createElement("div", {}, "bonus: if you define elements like this you don't need jsx")
    }
}
export default FreedomToClassComponents;
```

if any maintainers come across this -- please support class components if/whenever you can, especially for basic functionalities like this if it's not a big maintenance cost. Users might have reasons/opinions for organizing their code in flexible ways, which should be allowed.