# react get id from url with component

Tags: reactjs

I want to get id in url i tried both ways but i get an error can anyone help about the solution?

Error :

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See

`url: http://localhost:8080/passenger-update/16`

Following my code:

```
class PassengerUpdate extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        let { id } = useParams();
        console.log(id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PassengerUpdate;
```

`This Router Code`

```
<Routes>
   <Route exact path="/passenger-update/:id" element={<PassengerUpdate/>}/>
</Routes>
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^0.25.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of React router are you using ?

Comment: the version i used: 18.0.2

Comment: I get the id value without the class method but I can't get it like this.

Comment: That's your React version. Which version of "React Router" are you using ? The latest is 6. Check your package.json if you aren't sure.

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"

Comment: I shared the package.json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router-dom useParams() inside class component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548767/react-router-dom-useparams-inside-class-component)

Comment: Unfortunately when I use withRouter "'withRouter' passed (transmitted as 'withRouter') not found in 'react-router-dom'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useParams` is a hook & hence can be used either inside a function component or another hook only.

1. You can split `window.location.href` using '/' to access the id, in `componentDidMount`. (recommended)
2. If you are using React Router version <= 5 use
   `var PassengerUpdateWithRouter = withRouter(PassengerUpdate)`.
   This will make the `match` object (& `params`) availabe as a
   prop inside PassengerUpdate.
3. If you are using React Router 6, `withRouter` has been removed.
   i. Convert your class component to a function component. Now `useParams` will work. (not recommended for large components).
   ii. Create a higher order function component

```js
function withParams(Comp) {
    return (props)=> {
        var params = useParams();
        return <Comp {...props} params={params} />;
    }
}

var PassengerUpdateWithParams = withParams(PassengerUpdate);
// PassengerUpdateWithParams should replace PassengerUpdate' usage
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

See [react-router-dom useParams() inside class component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548767/react-router-dom-useparams-inside-class-component) for more information, especially @MahanVahdani's answer &
@k90mirzaei's comment (https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-jennings-l7qq93).

Comment: I applied what you said, but I couldn't find a solution, I'm a beginner in react js.
Could you compile the codes with the code I shared?

Comment: Which solution did you try ? Try the 1st one `window.location.href`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a small detail. Thanks a lot for your help