# How to bypass around not having to use usePararms in a class?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am new to ReactJS. So I want to upgrade this piece of code from react-router-dom-v4 to  react-router-dom-v6. I know that we can not use this.props.match.params.roomCode in v6 and I wanted to figure out how to upgrade this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function withHook(Component) { 
return function WrappedComponent(props) {
  const params = useParams();
// assuming :id is what you have on the route
  return <Room {...props} roomCode={params.id} />;
};
}

class Room extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  votesToSkip: 2,
  guestsCanPause: false,
  isHost: false,
};
//props.roomCode is what you want
}

getRoomDetails() {
fetch("/api/get-room" + "?code=" + this.roomCode)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      votesToSkip: data.votes_to_skip,
      guestCanPause: data.guest_can_pause,
      isHost: data.is_host,
      });
    });
   }

  render() {
   return (
   <div>
    <h3>{this.state.roomCode}</h3>
    <p>Votes: {this.state.votesToSkip}</p>
    <p>Guests Can Pause: {this.state.guestsCanPause.toString()}</p>
    <p>Host: {this.state.isHost.toString()}</p>
  </div>
);
  }
 }

 export default withHook(Room);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router-dom useParams() inside class component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548767/react-router-dom-useparams-inside-class-component) There are also answers for v6.

Comment: I tried going through that question. I was confused even after reading all the possible answers.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71884918/5597017) should solve your problem. Generally you wrap your class component into the another functional component (where you can use hooks) and pass params as a props.

Comment: As I said I am new to react, could you help me with a little more detailed explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks are not supported for class components

> You can’t use Hooks inside of a class component, but you can definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree. Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is an implementation detail of that component. In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both

If you still do not want to transform your class component to a functional one, add `roomCode` as a prop to your component and use an HOC to do the heavy lifting. Something like this

```
function withHook(Component) {
  return function WrappedComponent(props) {
    const params = useParams();
    // assuming :id is what you have on the route
    return <Room {...props} roomCode={params.id} />;
  }
}

class Room extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      votesToSkip: 2,
      guestsCanPause: false,
      isHost: false,
    };
    this.roomCode = this.props.roomCode;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h3>{this.roomCode}</h3>
          <p>Votes: {this.state.votesToSkip}</p>
          <p>Guests Can Pause: {this.state.guestsCanPause.toString()}</p>
          <p>Host: {this.state.isHost.toString()}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withHook(Room)
```

Or migrate to a functional component.. and this all goes away.

```
  const Room = () => {
    const {id: roomCode} = useParams()
    const [roomState, setRoomState] = useState({
      votesToSkip: 2,
      guestsCanPause: false,
      isHost: false,
    })
    
    return (<div>Room details</div>)
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have added the whole file. Could you please go over the exact syntax for the usage of a HOC for this?

Comment: Have updated the code to be more specific.. Haven't tested it on an older react version.. So do take it with a pinch of salt

Comment: Thanks! I have added another function I need, and I was wondering how I would extend the functionality to that.