# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'basename') when using react router useParams()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component `Post` that imports `useParams()` from `react-router-dom`. However, when I try to assign `useparams()` to a const to see the params I have it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'basename')
```

Here is how I am importing an assigning the params:

```
import { BrowserRouter as useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const { params } = useParams();
```

Here is my Post component:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as useParams } from "react-router-dom";

class Post extends React.Component {
  ...
 
  render() {
    const { params } = useParams();
    console.log(params)

    return(
      ...
    )
  }
}

export default Post;
```

I am using:

```
"react": "^18.2.0"
"react-router-dom": "^6.4.3"
"react-dom": "^18.2.0"
```

Comment: maybe

import { BrowserRouter as useParams } from "react-router-dom"; to 
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

Comment: @Neo if I do that it raises another error `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. `

Comment: Yes its because you can only use hooks inside functional component in my opinion you can make 2 things. First: convert your component to functional component Second: use HOC/wrapper component you can find an example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548767/react-router-dom-useparams-inside-class-component