# React-Router location with multiple search parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Normally I use these function for first search parameter.

```
history.push({
    pathname: props.location.pathname,
    search: "nice=yes"
})
```

and after these ***history.push*** link looks like this ***->*** `x.com/title?nice=yes`

But I can't add more search query. When i try to add new key only old key change.
For example my link is `x.com/title?nice=yes` and i add second search when page change, query looks like this;

```
history.push({
    pathname: props.location.pathname,
    search: "page=10"
})
```

But it changes first parameter.

I want add multiple parameters like this: `x.com/title?page=10&nice=yes`

Comment: What is you search type ? it is Object like { page: 10, nice: "yes" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have multiple parameters you have to put them in an object first :

```
const params = {
    page: 10,
    nice: "yes",
    size: 20,
    ...
}
```

then serialize them with this function :

```
const serialize = obj => Object.keys(obj)
                             .map(key => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[key])}`)
                             .join('&')
```

like this :

```
history.push({
    pathname: history.location.pathname,
    search: serialize(params) // => search: 'page=10&nice=yes&size=20&...'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, when you push the second time, you add the following query parameter `?page=10` to the pathname `x.com/title`

```
pathname: props.location.pathname, ==> x.com/title
```

If you want to add a new query parameter you have to check if there is a query parameter using a foreach on `this.props.location.query`, and if there is one, you add it to the pathname

That will look like this :

```
let currentPathname;

this.props.location.query.foreach(qparams => {
   currentPathname + qparams
});

history.push({
  pathname: this.currentPathname,
  search: "page=10"
})
```

There is  [a question related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Answer (score 0):

Create a string with multiple parameters

```
history.push({
    pathname: props.location.pathname,
    search: "page=10&nice=yes"
})
```

Comment: sometimes i need one parametere sometimes multi. not always two.