# How to access component parameters from app.js in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react app where the react-router is initialized in the App.js. When the url is `localhost:3000/id` the Home component is been rendered to the App.js, but i need to get the `id` variable from the App.js to run the `initBusinessDetails()` how can I access the `id` variable from the App.js.

App.js code

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { getBusiness } from './actions/GetBusinessDetails';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Categories from './components/Categories';

class App extends React.Component {




  initBusinessDetails(){
    console.log(this.props)

    const { params } = this.props.match
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/getBusiness?businessId=`+params.id)
    .then(res => {
      this.props.getBusiness(res.data)
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.initBusinessDetails();
  }

    render() {
        return (

           <div>
             {!this.props.business ?

                <div>
                  <ReactLoading type="bars" color="#000"/>
                </div>:
                <div>
                  <Router>
                    <Route exact path="/:id" component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact path="/:id/categories" component={Categories}/>
                    </Router>
                </div>
            }

          </div>
        )
      }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    business:state.business
  }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({getBusiness : getBusiness},dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,matchDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string 
Check this post on how to get parameters from querystring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Accessing Match Params**

A component being rendered under the `component` prop from `react-router-dom` also receives a [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) prop.

> You’ll have access to match objects in various places:
>
> - **Route component as this.props.match**
> - Route render as ({ match }) => ()
> - Route children as ({ match }) => ()
> - withRouter as this.props.match
> - matchPath as the return value

To access the `id` from it:

```
initBusinessDetails() {
  const { params } = this.props.match;
  axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/getBusiness?businessId=${params.id}`)
    .then(res => {
      this.props.getBusiness(res.data)
    });
}
```

**But this Code is Outside my Router**

Now this code is outside of your router, so you need to render something inside your router that can call that function. This is easy since you are still only using a `Router` so all matched routes are rendered (*As opposed to a `Switch` which only returns the first matched route*). Render another route with an inline functional component. Could do class-based as well, but would require a tweak in order to work. Let me know if this is the case.

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/:id"
  component={({ match }) => {
    // add any logic here to do anything when this component is 
    // mounted/rendered, like call `initBusinessDetails` with 
    // the `id` param
    return null; // return nothing to the UI
  }}
/>
```

Now, this will trigger that function whenever the router rerenders that route, so you may need to add logic out in `App` and your axios call to ensure you only initialize once. If you can use hooks, then an `useEffect` hook right in the inline functional component would do the trick.

```
initBusinessDetails(id) {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/getBusiness?businessId=${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      this.props.getBusiness(res.data)
    });
}

...

<Route
  exact
  path="/:id"
  component={({ match }) => {
    useEffect(
      () => initBusinessDetails(match.params.id),
      [] // call only once when mounted
    );
    return null; // return nothing to the UI
  }}
/>
```