# How can I access router params in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

Am trying to edit post by it's id and I would like pass the id a a prop to the EditPost component how do I go about it?

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <Switch >
        <Route path="/edit/:id">
          <EditPost index={/*what do I do here?*/} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

Comment: See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string).
You get it from props

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - How to get parameter value from query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Comment: I specifically wanted to do it in the jsx  `<EditPost index={/*what do I do here?*/} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `EditPost` component you can do it like this:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const EditPost = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  return <p>Your Post ID is: {params.id}</p>  
}

export default EditPost;
```

And make your route as:

```
<Route path="/edit/:id">
  <EditPost />
</Route>
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the component with class component, you can use next approach. Here is the component

```
const EditPost = ({ match }) => {
  let { id } = match.params
  // ...
}
```

or the same with hook:

```
const EditPost = () => {
  let { id } = useParams();
  // ...
}
```

And then in router you can use it like this:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/blog/:slug" component={BlogPost} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```