# deeplink in react router (hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I have following routes in the application:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/shops/:id">
       <StoreDetails/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="/shops">
        <Stores/>
    </Route>
   <Route path="/">
      <Home/>
   </Route>
</Switch>
```

how do I deep link /shops and /shops/:id URLs??

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string

Answer (score 2):

whith hooks :

```
import React from 'react';

export const test = props => {
 const { match } = props;
 const id = match.params.id;

 return <></>;
};
```