# How to get URL value in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I have this URL and a component that renders here.
I want to get 'id' from here: *localhost:8080/restaurants/2/feedback*. How to get value of id '2' in feedback controller that is gonna be rendered? Here is how it is written in code link

`<Route path="/restaurants/:id/feedback" component={Feedback} />`

**EDITED**:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.params.id;
    const data = await Api.getAllRestaurantFeedback('feedback?restaurantId=', id);
... 
...

Feedback.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

I have a warning here: *ESLint: 'params.id.id' is missing in props validation(react/prop-types)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - How to get parameter value from query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Answer (score 0):

Inside feedback you have match property. You can use it to get id. It is inside `match.params` as id most probably

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your component inside **withRouter** and then access the necessary params via its props . Something like **this.props.match.params.id**

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class Dummy extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { match } = this.props

    return (
      <div>Value of id {match.params.id}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Dummy);
```

Comment: do i really need withRouter when I use simple Route everywhere in app?

Comment: check the question, please, after EDITED