# How to get queryString from url?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, query-string

I am trying to get the key from the url, it's not getting anything,

this is the browser url for e.g i want like this

```
auth/reset-password/finish?key=123
```

i am setting the Route like this

```
 path: '/auth/reset-password/finish/:key?'
```

here is the main component

```
  const key = queryString.parse('key', location.search);
```

if i did the console, it's giving me null

i did console log the location it's giving me like this

```
pathname: "/auth/reset-password/finish"
search: "?key=Hci5deBRQJSofcD0aVru"
 hash: ""
 state: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: You can use the `match` object of `react-router`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**SOLUTION**]
So here is my answer to my problem

```
  const key = queryString.parse(location.search);
```

so if i did the console log.
 `console.log('keyssss', key);`
it's giving me the key-value thank you all for the time

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router you can get the query from the location object:

```
this.props.location.query.key
```

To  get the named params you can use:

```
this.props.match.params.key
```

EDIT: this solution applies to react-router 3 and below.

Comment: check you this.params to see if you have acces to location and match

Comment: I see, I think you are using react-router 4 or above which no longer parses the query string have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Comment: "react-router": "^5.1.2",
yes this the ver i am using

Comment: i got the solution.. it's because of the react-router version.. `    console.log(queryString.parse(location.search));
 this one works`

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Maybe you should create an answer for your own question now that you have found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If your path is path: **/auth/reset-password/finish/:key?**
so your route should be **/auth/reset-password/finish/123**

You can access key by **this.props.match.params.key**

here match you will get from **react-router**

Answer (score 0):

hope you well ,please check hope it will work

now this is function return a Object , have your all url paramerts

```js
      callDecodeUrl=(url)=>{
       var decodeURL = decodeURIComponent((url + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
       var query = queryString.parseUrl(decodeURL);
       return query.query
      }

 

    var url =  this.callDecodeUrl('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078853/is-there-way-to-get-querystring-from-url')
    console.log(url)
```