# react-router-dom: How do i get url parems passed, while passing other data?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I would like to have my Clubs get data straight from its parent. In the example below. other props such as data and setData are both available. but not id which should be given by the path.

```
<AuthRoute path="/club/:id">
 <Club data={data} setData={setData} />
</AuthRoute>

const AuthRoute = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
  return (
    <Route {...props}>
      {isAuthenticated ? children : <Redirect to="/login" />}
    </Route>
  );
};

export const Club = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <div>Hello World</div>;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - How to get parameter value from query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Comment: No, sadly I would have to change structure and if i did i would not be able to send the other data at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I used useParems function in Club that worked.

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the id in Club component by

```
export const Club = (props) => {
  let club_id = props.match.params.id;
  console.log('ClubId is::',club_id);
  return <div>Hello World</div>;
};
```

Comment: This gave me an error props.match is undefined. But thanks for giving it a try. :)