# How can I pass this URL parameter like this in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

http://localhost:8080/?companyKey=eefef-edd-dd-ddf

I want to pass the company key in my react project via URL

I used this method

```js
<Route exact path="/?companyKey=key"component={CompanySelectorFromKey} />
```

the method isn't working

Comment: Are trying to grab the `companyKey` parameters from the URL and render this `<Route exact path="/?companyKey=eefef-edd-dd-ddf" component={CompanySelectorFromKey} />`? Or are you trying to figure out how to get your `CompanySelectorFromKey` component to read the `companyKey` parameter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - How to get parameter value from query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Comment: I have to view that company key from the URL in CompanyKeySelecterFromKey Comonent

Comment: @brc-dd nope, please answer it simple

Answer (score 1):

`<Route path='/edit/:id' component={Edit} />`

And in edit component you are received this id by

`let id = props.match.params.id;`

Comment: it says props not found

Comment: you can used the class component class Edit extends Component {
 constructor(props,{match}){
    super()
    let id = props.match.params.id;
    this.state = {
    id : id,
   }
 }

Answer (score 0):

The way to pass parameters into a Route is like this `<Route exact path="/:companyKey" component={CompanySelectorFromKey} />`

Then in your `CompanySelectorFromKey`, you can read that parameter like so:

```
const company_key = props.match.params.companyKey;
```

So your page would actually have to be accessed this way:

```
http://localhost:8080/eefef-edd-dd-ddf
```

Here is a working Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sky-jp8rv?file=/src/App.js

Try accessing the preview side like this:

```
https://jp8rv.csb.app/eefef-edd-dd-ddf
```

and you will see the magic.

Comment: Thanks bro, is there any way to access via this way !   http://localhost:8080/?companyKey=eefef-edd-dd-ddf

Comment: @Theepag I have updated the Sanbox to work the way you want. You can access it this way now: https://jp8rv.csb.app/?companyKey=17212712321