# Access params in URL in JS (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this URL : `http://localhost:3000/#access_token=90kzif5gr8plhtl9286sc1z1qbgoj3&scope=moderation%3Aread&token_type=bearer`

and I want to get from this only the access_token value `90kzif5gr8plhtl9286sc1z1qbgoj3`

How can I do it in Javascript please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - How to get parameter value from query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Comment: it's not a query string, it's anchor text.

Comment: Check my answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
const url = "http://localhost:3000/#access_token=90kzif5gr8plhtl9286sc1z1qbgoj3&scope=moderation%3Aread&token_type=bearer";
const hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#') + 1);
let result = hash.split('&')
result = result[0].split('=')

console.log(result[1]); // "90kzif5gr8plhtl9286sc1z1qbgoj3"
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters) the simplest way is :

```
var url_string = "http://localhost:3000/#access_token=90kzif5gr8plhtl9286sc1z1qbgoj3&scope=moderation%3Aread&token_type=bearer"; 
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("access_token");
```

Comment: I get "null" for c

Comment: It's not gonna give you the value @shahryar ab

Comment: But Yes this works if you add `var c = url.searchParams.get(c);`
as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: it's not a query string, it's anchor text.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by splitting the URL `string` into three strings and using the access token directly then

```
var url=http://localhost:3000/#access_token=90kzif5gr8plhtl9286sc1z1qbgoj3&scope=moderation%3Aread&token_type=bearer
var firstHalf=url.split('#access_token=')[1];
var required_token=firstHalf.split("&scope")[0];
```

print the value of `required_token`.

Required result will be `"90kzif5gr8plhtl9286sc1z1qbgoj3"`

Answer (score 1):

your text is the string contained in [window.location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash), and a string of that format can be easily turned into a properly decoded key/value store using the [URLSearchParams constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams):

```js
const token = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash).get("access_token");
```