# Get parameter value from query string?

Tags: reactjs, shopify, react-router-dom

I am try to get a query string from a URL but am getting an error. I am using a reactjs project created with Shopify-CLI. I have tried the examples on
https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-query-strings/
https://ui.dev/react-router-v5-query-strings/

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Users extends Component {
  render() {
const { id } = this.props.match.params;

return (
  <div>
    <h1>User id is {id}</h1>
  </div>
);
}  
}

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install query-string package `npm install query-string`

```
 import queryString from 'query-string';

    console.log(location.search);
    // Output: '?id=1&name=abc'

    const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
    console.log(parsed);
    // Output: {id: "1", name: "abc"}

    console.log(location.hash);
    // Output: '#id=1&name=abc'
```

For different approach you can look: [React - How to get parameter value from query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/react-how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string/53079875#53079875)

Moreover, as your error shows `props` is undefined. If you are already parsing and getting the values in props from parent component then try logging the props value. Else you can directly use query-string.

```
const value=queryString.parse(this.props.location.search);
const token=value.token;
console.log('token',token)//123
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function getUrlVars() {

   let vars = {};
   let parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
   });

   return vars;
}
```

use it :

```
let number = getUrlVars()["x"];
let mytext = getUrlVars()["text"];
```

source: https://html-online.com/articles/get-url-parameters-javascript/