# React: how to access url's parameters

Tags: reactjs

How can I get the url params from a route?
I got this code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>

          <Route path="/table/:name/" element={<SortingTable/>}></Route>
          <Route path="" exact element={<BasicTable/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to get the `name` from the url and use it in SortingTable:

```
  
const SortingTable = ({match}) => {

    let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState([])
    const table = match.params.name //=> undefined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get parameter value from query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352638/how-to-get-parameter-value-from-query-string)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **`useParams`**:

```js
const { name } = useParams();
```

**Note:** When you want to get the queries from the URL, you can use the **`useSearchParams`**, But when you want to get the params you defined in your `Route` component and `path` prop, you can use the **`useParams`**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use useParams from React Router

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProfilePage() {
  // Get the userId param from the URL.
  let { userId } = useParams();
  // ...
}
```