# getting the value of query string in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-string

i have a url like this

```
http://localhost:9001/search_results?r
```

I'm using querystring to take the value of 'r' like this. (I'm using a react library)

```
componentDidMount() {

        const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
        console.log("Character",parsed);

}
```

In  my log i get a value like `{r: null}` How can i get only the value of 'r' from this?

Comment: there is no value assigned for r, set url like r=something to get the value of r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting query parameters from react-router hash fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852998/getting-query-parameters-from-react-router-hash-fragment)

Comment: @Rajesh He's trying to find `r` from the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query string parameters may have both keys and values, such as `http://localhost:9001/search_results?key1=value1&key2=value2`. For this reason, you're being given an object with both keys and their values. `?r` is a query string with a key "r" with no value (`null`), thus `{r: null}`.

If you want a simple array of the keys, and don't care for the values you can simply use `Object.keys()` then select the first one:

```js
var parsed = {r: null};

var keys = Object.keys(parsed);

console.log(keys);
console.log(keys[0]);
```