# How to extract query param from URL in react?

Tags: reactjs, express, url

I have a React app being built and then served by an express server. I need to be able to access a query parameter `url.com/?param=somevalue` in the URL from within the React app (not the server). The app will then fetch data from an API using the parameter value

As the app is very simple it does not require any routing, thus I'm not using any routing such as react-router. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error are you getting? This simple google search may help: https://www.google.com/search?q=react+get+url+params&oq=react+get+url+p

Comment: Best answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852998/getting-query-parameters-from-react-router-hash-fragment